# Can you join 2 PIVOT SQL views - is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, pivot

I am trying to figure out how I can do this without repeating the same code few time.
Table script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ztblMain](
    [ID] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Invoice_NBR] [bigint] NULL,
    [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR] [bigint] NULL,
    [tran_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tran_Amount] [numeric](15, 2) NULL,
    [PAYMENT_METHOD] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [GF_L1] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 194167, CAST(N'2020-08-18T08:25:12.530' AS DateTime), CAST(2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'EFT', N'4710')
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 193397, CAST(N'2020-08-17T12:22:25.713' AS DateTime), CAST(2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'Credit Card', N'1008')
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 193397, CAST(N'2020-07-27T09:44:25.937' AS DateTime), CAST(-2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'Credit Card', N'1008')
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 193397, CAST(N'2020-08-17T12:22:25.713' AS DateTime), CAST(-2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'Credit Card', N'4710')
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 194167, CAST(N'2020-08-18T08:25:12.530' AS DateTime), CAST(-2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'EFT', N'1009')
INSERT [dbo].[ztblMain] ([ID], [Invoice_NBR], [PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR], [tran_date], [tran_Amount], [PAYMENT_METHOD], [GF_L1]) VALUES (N'05DC1', 319126, 193397, CAST(N'2020-07-27T09:44:25.937' AS DateTime), CAST(2000.00 AS Numeric(15, 2)), N'Credit Card', N'4710')
GO
```

I need only to return one line pivoted by [GF_L1] field.

I build a simple view to pivot by GF_L1 field:

```
select *
from 
(
  select
        ID  
        , GF_L1
        , INVOICE_NBR
        , PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR
        , TRAN_DATE as PMNT_DATE
        , Action        
        , GF_COD
        , FEEITEM_SEQ_NBR
        , PAYMENT_METHOD
        , GF_FEE
        , TRAN_AMOUNT
    from  ztblMain
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX( tran_Amount ) 
    FOR [GF_L1] in ( [1008], [1009], [4710] )
) as PVT
```

Out of 3 returned rows from this PIVOT view I have to pick only 1 row where at least totals of 2 columns out of 3 :[1008], [1009] and [4710] would not be 0. In tis example - it is  a row with ETF payment type. I need to exclude other 2 rows that are actually payment and a refund.

Again used PIVOT view to return only 1 line I am in  interested in :

```
select
   ttt.ID
   , ttt.PAYMENT_SEQ_nbr 
   , ttt.INVOICE_NBR
   , ttt.FEEITEM_SEQ_NBR
   , ttt.PAYMENT_METHOD
from (
   select * 
   from (
       select
           ID  
           , GF_L1
           , INVOICE_NBR
           , PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR
           , TRAN_DATE as PMNT_DATE
           , Action        
           , GF_COD
           , FEEITEM_SEQ_NBR
           , PAYMENT_METHOD
           , GF_FEE
           , TRAN_AMOUNT
       from  ztblMain                       
   ) as SourceTable
   PIVOT
   (
       MAX( tran_Amount ) 
       FOR [GF_L1] in ( [1008], [1009], [4710] )
   ) as PVT
) as ttt
GROUP BY 
   ttt.ID
   , ttt.INVOICE_NBR
   , ttt.FEEITEM_SEQ_NBR
   , ttt. PAYMENT_METHOD
   , ttt.PAYMENT_SEQ_nbr
HAVING SUM(iSNULL(ttt.[1008],0)) <> 0
   or SUM(iSNULL(ttt.[1009],0)) <> 0
   or SUM(iSNULL(ttt.[4710],0)) <> 0
```

The expected result should be 1 row.

The problem I am facing:  I cannot join these 2 pivot views to get other fields I need.

**ID    INVOICE_NBR   PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR   PMNT_DATE   Action             GF_COD FEEITEM_SEQ_NBR PAYMENT_METHOD GF_FEE 1008   1009     4710 **

05DC1   319126         194167          2020-08-18   Payment Applied
INS    475242              EFT       2000.00  NULL -2000.00 2000.00

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this or I am missing something?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How does the expected result looks like ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69308716/edit) and update into the question

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add expected results *as text* not pictures

Comment: "I build a simple view to pivot by GF_L1 field:" : your query uses columns which are not in the table! We cannot execute it in order to discuss it. please check your sample table/data and provide something that you tested and we can discuss

Answer (score 0):

Using windowing functions might help you out. Below I have included an example that returns the one row you requested. I replaced the pivot function for a sum function with a case statement as I think it is easier to read (and understand).

```
With TransactionsWindowed As (
Select *
, NetTransactionAmount = SUM(tran_Amount) Over( Partition By ID, Invoice_NBR, PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR, GF_L1 Order By tran_date)
-- Using windowing function to calculate the net transaction of transaction that have the same characteristics.
, LastTransaction = ROW_NUMBER() Over( Partition By ID, Invoice_NBR, PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR, GF_L1 Order By tran_date DESC)
-- Using row_number function for marking the last transaction.
From [dbo].[ztblMain]
), RelevantTransactions As (
Select *
From TransactionsWindowed 
Where LastTransaction = 1
And NetTransactionAmount <> 0 -- If the sum of all transactions equals zero, we can ignore it.
)
Select ID
, Invoice_NBR
, PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR
, tran_date
, PAYMENT_METHOD
, [1008] = SUM(CASE WHEN GF_L1 = '1008' THEN tran_Amount END)
, [1009] = SUM(CASE WHEN GF_L1 = '1009' THEN tran_Amount END)
, [4710] = SUM(CASE WHEN GF_L1 = '4710' THEN tran_Amount END)
From RelevantTransactions
Group By ID, Invoice_NBR, PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR, tran_date, PAYMENT_METHOD
```

The result from the query is:

```
ID    Invoice_NBR          PAYMENT_SEQ_NBR      tran_date               PAYMENT_METHOD                 1008                                    1009                                    4710
----- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
05DC1 319126               194167               2020-08-18 08:25:12.530 EFT                            NULL
```

Your example included some columns that are not included in the sample dataset. You might want to extend the query above to include those missing columns.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. I knew nothing about these functions and need to look into this.
I was able to solve my issue by using With CTE functions but your solution looks more easy.  I am very interested to try it out.

Thank you for you help!